# php and mysqli SELECT query if it exists, then update it, else insert it

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am running a query to check my database for existing values, if they do exist then update them do not reinsert them.

Currently my code is just reinserting the values into the table instead of updating them, which means my code is never reaching the else part of my statement.

```
if(isset($user_info->error)){
    // Something's wrong, go back
    header('Location: twitter_login.php');
} 
else {
   // Let's find the user by its ID
   $query = ("SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' && oauth_uid = '".$user_info->id."'");
   $rs=$mysql->query($query);
   $results = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   // If not, let's add it to the database
   if(empty($result)){
      $query = ("INSERT INTO twitter (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, oauth_token, oauth_secret)
                 VALUES ('twitter', {$user_info->id}, '{$user_info->screen_name}', '{$access_token['oauth_token']}', '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}')");
      $rs=$mysql->query($query);
      $insert = ("SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE id = " . mysqli_insert_id($mysql));
      $rs=$mysql->query($insert);
      $results = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   } 
else{
    // Update the tokens
    $update = ("UPDATE twitter SET oauth_token = '{$access_token['oauth_token']}',
                oauth_secret = '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}'
                WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND oauth_uid = {$user_info->id}");
    $rs=$mysql->query($update);
    $rs->close();
}
```

Comment: It is reinserting the values into the database = duplicate rows... I don't want that.

Comment: `$results` or `$result` ? Cause you check for `empty($result)`

Comment: Try this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo between `$result` and `$results`

```
$results = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    // If not, let's add it to the database
    if(empty($result)){
                    ^
                   Here
```

as `$result` is not declared before it will always be empty and the if part will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to properly prevent duplicates, create a UNIQUE KEY(oauth_provider,oauth_uid);

then use INSERT ON DUPLICATE statement to insert or update the row.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO twitter (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, oauth_token, oauth_secret)
VALUES ('twitter', {$user_info->id}, '{$user_info->screen_name}', '{$access_token['oauth_token']}', '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE oauth_token = VALUES(oauth_token), oauth_secret = VALUES(oauth_secret)
```

Comment: would this eliminate my last `else { update }` statement? @naktibalda

Comment: yes, it replaces SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE in your code.